# Difference between BoolFilterBuilder VS boolquerybuilder vs FilteredQueryBuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-1.6.0

I've been using boolquerybuilder. The results are fine.
Whats the purpose of using BoolFilterBuilder and FilteredQueryBuilder.
can i use them instead of boolquerybuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.0 Filtered Query is removed.

Use the bool query instead with a `must` clause for the query and a `filter` clause for the filter

[see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-compound-queries.html#java-query-dsl-filtered-query)

by